# Can't install SSL for Python 2.7.13 on OS X

Tags: macos, python-2.7, openssl, pip, pyopenssl

I tried to solve the OpenSSL 0.9.8 v issue on Mac and accidentally deleted the ssl library. While trying to get them back I get the following errors:

```
pip install ssl
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting ssl
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ssl/: There was a problem confirming the
  ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ssl
```

Any idea how I can get it there back?
Thanks!

Comment: *"I tried to solve the OpenSSL 0.9.8v issue on Mac and accidentally deleted the ssl library."* - If you deleted Apple's library in `/usr`, then you are in a bad place. You likely broke a number of system utilities, like `wget` and `curl`. You should work on restoring Apple's library first. You may have to perform a system restore. Also see [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) in Apple Support and [Is there anything like System Restore for Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53117/83961) on Apple Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yea, it was a jackass move. I just reinstalled Mac OS and it seems to bring back the ssl files.